# express.js / postgresql Get request returns []

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, crud

I have a table that stores id, user_name, state & city. When I send a request to get * from my table, I get the expected results. When I send my request based on the city, I get a 200 response, but the return only shows []. The column I'm hitting is not an integer, so I feel like  const city = **parseInt**(request.params.city) is not correct, but I can't find anything online that calls out what should replace **parseInt**, if that's the issue. What am I missing?

When calling http://localhost:8080/info I get the expected results:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_name": "Mike J",
    "state": "California",
    "city": "San Francisco"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "user_name": "Emily R",
    "state": "Florida",
    "city": "Tampa"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "user_name": "Tyrone S",
    "state": "New Mexico",
    "city": "Las Vegas"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "user_name": "Eduardo G",
    "state": "Texas",
    "city": "Austin"
}
```

When adding the city to the call http://localhost:8080/info/Tampa I get:

```
[]
```

Here is my code:

**index:**

```
const express = require('express')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

const db = require('./queries')

const port = 8080

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (_request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.get('/info', db.getInfo)
app.get('/info/:city', db.getInfoByCity)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

**queries:**

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({
  user: '//',
  host: '//',
  database: '//',
  password: '//',
  port: 5432,
})

const getInfo = (_request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_info ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

const getInfoByCity = (request, response) => {
    const city = parseInt(request.params.city)

    pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE city = $1', [city], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
     })
  }

  module.exports = {
    getInfo,
    getInfoByCity,
  }
```

Here is my user_info table (id, user_name, state, city)

```
1   "Mike J"    "California"    "San Francisco"

2   "Emily R"   "Florida"   "Tampa"

3   "Tyrone S"  "New Mexico"    "Las Vegas"

4   "Eduardo G" "Texas" "Austin"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this:

```
    const city = parseInt(request.params.city)
```

Clearly this is a mistake. The city is a string, not an integer. Just replace with

```
    const city = request.params.city
```